# what are most important things that i must know in order to jump into silverlight development

Tags: silverlight

I have vast programming knowledge; C++/C#/ActionScript/ASM/PHP..... so learning the language of SilverLight itself isn't of an issue.

To keep long story short, when asking this question I'm asking it as a developer who's coming from Flash world - great graphics/sounds/media support, fully cross-platform, ability to combine several SWFs within a "movie" (which also implies code reusability).
A Flash developer have pretty much freedom.

What are most important things that i must know in order to jump into silverlight development?
Did you already make the move to SilverLight from Flash yourself? Are you a "guru" at both? Great, let's hear what you have to say - developer to developer! =)

Edit #1:
One thing; I'm not talking about forms/office apps but rather game development with grphics/animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned WPF a few years ago after a number of years developing in Flex/Flash.  The biggest hurdle for me was getting a handle on XAML and the way templating and "styling" works.

**1. Approach with an open mind**

While there are styles in WPF and Sliverlight, they bear little resemblance to the CSS used in Flex or HTML.  The biggest piece of advice I could give you is forget about how you THINK styling should work and approach with an open mind.

**2.  Download code examples**

Find yourself some code examples and tutorials and dive in! http://www.silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/silverlight-4/ is a good place to start.

**3. Get Expression Blend**

Get expression Blend and dig into control templating.  The GUI should be familiar to you.  When you drag a control onto the canvas, you can right click and select "Edit Template".  This will give you an idea of how controls are built, and how to use the various layout components (Grid, Border, Stackpanel), that are available.